# Beginning algorithm for the game black jack

Tags: c++, algorithm, blackjack

I have to come up with a program for the first part of the game black jack. The problem asks to come up with 2 random cards and their total with an input of 52 cards in the deck. I can do this easily if I set the deck to 13 (number of different cards in the deck) but I'm having problems calculating with 52. I cannot use if else or switch statements for the cards. My problem is my calculation of total. When my seed input for the srand is set to -22 I get an incorrect value for total. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

const int CARDS_IN_DECK = 52;
int main()
{
    int seed, i;
    double card, total;
    cout << "Enter the seed for the random number generator: ";
    cin >> seed;
    srand(seed);
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.precision(0);
    for(i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        card = rand() % CARDS_IN_DECK + 1;
        card = (card + 1) / 4.0;
        if(card >= 10) {
            card = 10;
        }
        total += card;
        if(i == 0) {
            cout << "Your first card is " << card << endl;
        } else if(i == 1) {
            cout << "Your second card is " << card << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "Your total points are " << total;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i ran your code many times and got the correct total for seed value -22 ! Can you clarify your question.Also i would like to add that srand takes an unsigned int as seed value.

Comment: Be aware that this algorithm doesn't really give the correct odds. If you play with one deck, the chance of drawing e.g. two nines is 4/52 * 3/51, whereas here it's 4/52 * 4/52.

Comment: Drawing two cards and calculating their sum are two separate operations; check the results of the first one, and you'll know which one is going wrong (and then you can eliminate the other one from your example).

Comment: advice: declare all you variables as unsigned integer (`unisgned int seed, i, card, total`). But you will not go far with this approach anyway (I have written my own BJ simulator in the past to evaluate strategies). Better declare a class for cards, put cards in a array (the deck), shuffle the deck and pick randomly from the deck.

Comment: I've made all of my variables unsigned int and that has simplified things. With a seed input of -22 my professor is getting 5+2=7 where as I am getting 4+1=5. When the seed is a positive number we get the same answers but when seed is negative I am wrong. Any ideas?